# How can I group two joined tables

Tags: oracle, join, group-by, union

How can I group (by) two joined tables (in an Oracle database) like this:

```
cant:
id      CANT_VAL    COD_VAL fk_id_chest
18059   18.56       R12     1
18060   11          R10     2
18061   15          R11     3

col:
FK_ID_COL_DMA   CANT_VAL    COD_VAL
18059           1134        R10
18059           1234        R3
18061           1111        R5
```

to look like that:

```
id      CANT_VAL    COD_VAL    fk_id_chest
18059   18.56       R12        1
18059   1134        R10        1
18059   1234        R3         1
18060   11          R10        2
18061   15          R11        3
18061   1111        R5         3
```

fk_id_chest is a "link" to another table that I need in the final result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, thanks!

```
select cant.id,CANT.CANT_VAL,CANT.COD_VAL,CANT.FK_ID_CHEST from cant
union
select COL.FK_ID_COL_DMA,COL.CANT_VAL,COL.COD_VAL,CANT.FK_ID_CHEST from col 
    inner join cant
        on cant.id=COL.FK_ID_COL_DMA
```